# How to pass along get parameters in Django?

Tags: django

Lets suppose a user enters your page and navigates through some pages:

```
start_page > a_page > another_page > finish_page
```

Assuming a GET parameter was set when the navigation started in the first page (start), how do I carry on passing this parameter through the other pages? I don't want to hard code the parameter in any of these pages because each of them could have a lot of links, leading to other pages.

Should it be accomplished through a middleware?

Comment: You could use the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman and store into a cookie?

Comment: You shouldn't care where the session data is stored,v the framework takes care of that for you.

Comment: I see. I have read the documentation on this subject. Sounds perfect to my needs. Thanks!